# Prove that $\lfloor n\sqrt{2}\rfloor $ doesn't satisfy any linear recurrence with constant coefficients.

Tags: recurrence-relations, real-numbers

Prove that $\lfloor n\sqrt{2}\rfloor $ doesn't satisfy any linear recurrence with constant coefficients. 
Using one of the formula for floor function, we can write:
$$ \lfloor n\sqrt{2}\rfloor =\frac{-1}{2}+n\sqrt{2}+\frac{\arctan \cot{n\pi \sqrt{2}}}{\pi}.$$ Can we use this representation somehow to prove our claim.

Comment: I would think just the definition of  the floor function and the irrationality of $\sqrt2$ should be enough. I personally don't see how involving $\arctan, \cot$ and $\pi$ is really going to help.

Comment: Hint: If a sequence $\left(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots\right)$ satisfies a linear recurrence with constant coefficients, then so does $\left(a_1 - a_0, a_2 - a_1, a_3 - a_2, \ldots\right)$.

Comment: Finding one formula that is not a recurrence with constant coefficients does not prove that there is not another one that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\,a_n(x) := \lfloor n\,x\rfloor\, $ satisfied any linear recurrence with constant coefficients, and letting $\,y := x-\lfloor x\rfloor,\,$ then so would $\,a_n(y),\,$ and since $\,0\le y<1,\,$ the first difference sequence $\,b_n(y) := a_{n+1}(y) - a_n(y)\,$ is one also and satisfies $\, b_n(y) \in \{0,1\}$ because
for all real $\,z\,$, we have $\,\lfloor z\rfloor \le \lfloor z+y \rfloor \le \lfloor z\rfloor+1.\,$ But now $\,b_n(y)\,$ must be eventually periodic and this implies $\,y\,$ is rational and then so is $\,x.\,$ This is from the theorem that $\,\lfloor n\,x\rfloor - n\,x\,$ is periodic if and only if $\,x\,$ is rational.

Notice that any recurrence of the form
 $$\,a_{n+k} = f(a_n, a_{n+1}, \dots, a_{n+k-1}) \tag{1}$$ for all $n$ with a fixed $k$ and such that the range of the sequence is a finite set, then there is only a finite number of $k$-tuples and so the function on $k$-tuples given by $$ (a_n,\dots,a_{n+k-1}) \mapsto \,(a_{n+1},\dots,a_{n+k}), \tag{2}$$ where $\,a_{n+k}\,$ is given by equation $(1)$, maps a finite set into itself and hence must be eventually periodic.

Comment: What if we don't know the irrationality of x?

Comment: I am very sorry about my careless downvote. Now all my questions are answered in your edit, I would like to retract my downvote, but the it is not letting me to do so. It seems that if the answer is edited again, then it is possible to change my vote.

Comment: Ah, it worked. I added one blank character to your answer, and retracted my downvote, changed to an upvote.

Comment: @i707107 No problem. I can take a few downvotes even if by mistake. Nice work on retraction.